# S101 Use of assert detected for python tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, flake8

When I wrote unit test for a function and ran `flake8 test_function().py`, I received the following error:

> S101 Use of assert detected. The enclosed code will be removed when compiling to optimised byte code.

**My question:**

1. How can I write unit tests without using `assert` keyword?
2. Should we ignore unit tests from the flake8 configuration?

Answer (score 30):

imo B101 (from bandit) is one of the worst "error" codes to enforce -- almost noone runs with `-O` in python because (1) it doesn't make things faster and (2) many third party libraries use assert defensively and disabling it can change behaviour

calling `assert` a "security problem" is alarmist at best

that said, the error code makes no sense in tests so I would recommend disabling it there:

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    tests: S101
```

you can also disable it via bandit's configuration, though I'm less familiar with that

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer